# Saving encrypted empty string with AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a VARBINARY field that is used to keep an encrypted string, using AES_ENCRYPT.

This field is optional and, by default, has a NULL value. But when inserting data to the table, even if the value for this field is an empty string, it became filled with a binary value (ie: 0xE7DBCC0F8E5B3257E899F8FB6291D6A2)

About the above situation, my questions are:

1. Is NULL the best default value for my VARBINARY field?
2. Is it normal to have this binary "garbage" in a VARBINARY field? I mean, it will increase my table size, doesn't it?
3. How to keep this VARBINARY NULL (or empty) when inserting an empty string?

My SQL knowledge is very limited, I appreciate any idea about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you encrypting an empty string?

Comment: How are you inserting data into the table?  What does `DESCRIBE yourTable` show (did you set `DEFAULT NULL`)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, well, I have the procedure for insertion and update, and as the field is optional, an empty string can be used.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, my SQL knowledge is limited, I am inserting data using the "normal" way INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2). Yes, the default value for the VARBINARY field is NULL, is this correct?

Comment: @Guybrush: If the field has a default value of `NULL`, then it should insert a NULL if you exclude that field from the `INSERT` query.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, can this IF be inserted in the SQL itself, like: If value = empty then insert null, otherwise insert the value? Or must I check it outside SQL ?

Comment: There's the [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function: `INSERT INTO yourTable (enc) VALUES (IF(@value = '', NULL, AES_ENCRYPT(@value, @key));`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, this will help me! Thanks!

Comment: @Guybrush That doesn't really answer my question, but I bet you do encrypt it. Just don't do it. Why don't you just edit the question and show the code you have problems with?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yes, I was encrypting the empty string by mistake, but now I am verifing if it is empty or not, and only encrypt when it is not empty (@RocketHazmat tip)... Thanks!